# Transfering data between Lua scripts and Java application with LuaJava

Tags: java, lua, luajava

I've read many great things about LuaJava (library). However, I still can't find any good documentation on **how to transfer data between the Lua scripts and Java application**. How is this done? I apologize if I missed a tutorial somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

There's a reference manual here: http://www.keplerproject.org/luajava/manual.html.
The Java documentation is at the bottom.

Here's an example (although it might be a bit out-dated): http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2003-12/msg00286.html

You might want to start with understanding the C interface to Lua. The LuaJava interface is built on that. The basic idea is that you have a stack and you first push the function, followed by arguments, and then you can execute a function in Lua. The results are then pushed on the stack and you can get data back from Lua that way.